# configuring devise to be read only for users but full CRUD for Admin in Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am a junior developer building an e-commerce web application using rails 4.2.4, Devise and a Pin scaffolding.

Right now, users can signup, sign in and then CREATE, READ UPDATE, DESTROY a pin on the index.html.erb.

Issue: I *do not want* users who sign in to be able to CRUD ( ONLY READ ).

I want to set this up so I as an ADMIN Can only create, update or destroy. Users and guests can only read.

I have been struggling with this for weeks, and would be grateful for help as to how I could achieve this please.

> This is my PinsController

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:search].present? && !params[:search].nil?
      @pins = Pin.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else
      @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
    authorize(@pin)
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end


private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

> This is my Index.html.erb

```
<h1>For Sale</h1>

<%= form_tag pins_path, method: :get do %> 
<div class="field">
<%= label_tag :Description %>
<%= text_field_tag :search %> 
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
<%= link_to 'Clear', pins_path, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm' %>
<% end %>

<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= pin.description %>
        <%= link_to 'Show', pin_path(pin) %>
        <% if current_user && pin.user == current_user %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <%= will_paginate @pins, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>

<div class=text-right>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to 'Post a Free Ad', new_pin_path, class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<br>
```

Comment: i think you should use some authorisation gems like https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization cancan rolify or pundit

Comment: I've installed Pundit, but its a nightmare to work. I can get it working but it does not discriminate between user and me as the admin and BLOCKS the page

Comment: How do you identify an `admin`? Or do you mean something like the pin's owner (the `pin.user`)?

Comment: @spickermann This is another part of the puzzle. I have done a migration add_admin_to_users and attempted to set such in the rails console. I don even know if this is the right methodology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want everybody (logged in users or just quests) to be able to access the `index` and the `show` method. All other methods are exclusively for administrators.

First step: We need a way to identify an administrator. Add a boolean `admin` attribute to your the `User` model. Run the following command on your command line to create a new migration:

```
$ rails g migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```

Open the generated file and add `default: false` to it, it should look like this:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Now run `rake db:migrate` to add that column to your database.

Next step it to grant your own user administration rights. Log into the rails console (with `$ rails c`). Find your user and update the `admin` flag on your user to `true`:

```
> user = User.find_by(email: 'your-eamiladdress@example.tld')
> user.admin = true
> user.save
> user.admin?
# => true
```

As you see Rails automatically adds a `admin?` method to the user. We use that method in the controller now:

```
before_action :find_pin,           only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :ensure_admin,       except: [:index, :show]
```

With this `private` methods:

```
def find_pin
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id]) # renders 404 in production when pin isn't found
end

def ensure_admin
  unless current_user.admin?
    redirect_to(pins_path, notice: 'Not authorized to edit this pin')
  end
end
```

Use the same `admin?` method in the view to hide `edit` and `destroy` links from non-admins:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', pin_path(pin) %>
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It pains me to have to ask a man of your credentials such a retarded question. How will the system know that I am the Admin

Comment: I basically can not have folks who login having access to create and detroy and update as this is the owners products for sale,  THE ADMIN should be able to CRUD. In a nutshell, I will can CRUD, everyone else, VIEW

Comment: The `ensure_owner` method ensures that only the pin's owner can manage the pin. If you also want admins to be able to manage all pins, than your user model needs some kind of flag (link a `boolean :admin`). That would allow to change the check to: `unless current_user.admin? || current_user == @pin.user`. The more complex your rules are, the more it makes sense to use a gem like `pundit` or `cancancan`

Comment: The reason I went down the route of trying to tweek devise was that I installed Pundit and it works to an extent but it was not differentiating between I(the admin) and the user and blocking everyone, hence tweeking this

Comment: I am trying to understand your code before I deploy it. Should my new code have 3 separate before actions. Above you have written 3 separate before actions

Comment: Yes, you need three different `before_actions`. I reformatted my answer, I hope that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: so grateful for you to do this on your weekend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102779/discussion-between-chris-dormani-and-spickermann).